# why won't rails find rabl templates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabl

working on an api, using the rails-api and rabl gems, basing understanding off railscasts 348 and 322

currently getting

```
Missing template activities/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :rabl]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/jd/Dropbox/honeybadgerconsulting/activitiesapi/app/views"
```

but best I can tell, my setup mirrors the screencasts,  is there a detail i'm overlooking ?

controller is

```
class ActivitiesController < ApplicationController
  include ActionController::ImplicitRender

  def index
    @activities = Activity.all
  end

end
```

and path to rabl template is /app/views/activities/index.json.rabl

context of json.rabl

```
collection @activities

attributes :title, :vendor, :date, :start_time, :price
```

[image: screenshot of files and dir strcuture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request URL has to end in ".json", rails thinks it's an HTML request.

Comment: snap, i just notice that I wasn't requesting to the correct endpoint... i swear, i've done this before !